# Why is there a leak seems at the rim of wheel

Tags: oil, leak, suzuki, scooter

[image]

There is a leak at the rim of wheel for my scooter
Suzuki swish
The more it rides the more it seems

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you talking about the black goo on your wheel?

Comment: Yes, the black grease like substance

Answer (score 1):

That "black goo" is from the failed hub or bearing seal.

It needs replacing and most likely the bearing as well.

This should be done asap, as it **will** breakdown.

Comment: Is it expensive to do that

Comment: Depends on your country parts may be **very** expensive or labor or both...